# Conversion of System.Array to List

Tags: c#, arrays, list, type-conversion

Last night I had dream that the following was impossible. But in the same dream, someone from SO told me otherwise.  Hence I would like to know if it it possible to convert `System.Array` to `List`

```cs
Array ints = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), 5);
ints.SetValue(10, 0);
ints.SetValue(20, 1);
ints.SetValue(10, 2);
ints.SetValue(34, 3);
ints.SetValue(113, 4);
```

to

```cs
List<int> lst = ints.OfType<int>(); // not working
```

Comment: Below link show how it does in c#
http://www.codegateway.com/2011/12/c-convert-array-to-list-and-list-to.html

Comment: You have to cast the `Array` to what it actually is, an `int[]`, then you can use `ToList`: `((int[])ints).ToList();`

Comment: @naserasadi please consider accepting the answer by Tim Schmelter as this is appears to be the correct answer to your question and even 12 years later this question is showing at the top of search results. Thanks!

Comment: Why to use System.Array at the first place? I think that need for using System.Array has died out long time ago. Just use typed arrays like int[] or  IMyType[], or Lists... You will never have these type of problems.

Comment: @A.Dzebo Enum.GetValues() returns System.Array.

Comment: @puzzl that's fine. Just convert it to a list using i.e. LINQ like this:
            List<Days> data = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Days)).OfType<Days>().Select(o => o).ToList();

and work with the list.

Answer (score 517, accepted):

Save yourself some pain...

```
using System.Linq;

int[] ints = new [] { 10, 20, 10, 34, 113 };

List<int> lst = ints.OfType<int>().ToList(); // this isn't going to be fast.
```

Can also just...

```
List<int> lst = new List<int> { 10, 20, 10, 34, 113 };
```

or...

```
List<int> lst = new List<int>();
lst.Add(10);
lst.Add(20);
lst.Add(10);
lst.Add(34);
lst.Add(113);
```

or...

```
List<int> lst = new List<int>(new int[] { 10, 20, 10, 34, 113 });
```

or...

```
var lst = new List<int>();
lst.AddRange(new int[] { 10, 20, 10, 34, 113 });
```

Comment: Note for completeness: the 2nd method is only available in C# 3.0+.

Comment: Since the int array already implements `IEnumerable<int>`, the `OfType<int>()` is not required. `ints.ToList();` suffices.

Comment: For OfType, you need System.Linq

Comment: I tried this and it slowed my program down immensly compared to just putting it manually in a list with a for loop

Comment: @kenny made some tweaks, the first method here, is definitely not the quickest way to do this.

Comment: None of these examples actually answer the actual question. But I guess he accepted the answer so he was happy. Still, not one of these actually convert an Array to a List. "Conversion of System.Array to List". Should add that example for completeness IMO. (Being top answer and all)

Comment: @SørenUllidtz The first example does exactly that.

Comment: @Dave It's true that OfType will work for the Array class, it's just not using the Array class in the example. And judging by the second comment I'm not the only one who got confused about that.

Comment: System.Linq in .Net 4.0 is in System.Core: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893601/where-is-system-linq-in-net-4-0

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Enum.GetValues(typeof(Enumtype)).Cast<itemtype>().ToList()

Comment: You can create the list by given array List<string> list = new List<string>(array);

Comment: Why does this not answer the question?

Comment: Why did so many people up vote this when it does not answer to question that was asked?

Answer (score 108):

There is also a constructor overload for List that will work... But I guess this would required a strong typed array.

```
//public List(IEnumerable<T> collection)
var intArray = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var list = new List<int>(intArray);
```

... for Array class

```
var intArray = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), 5);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    intArray.SetValue(i, i);
var list = new List<int>((int[])intArray);
```

Comment: Between this approach and the one using `ToList()`, which is more efficient? Or is there a difference?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing the real dataset size (List internally uses arrays that must be able to expand.  Arrays are immutable.)  If you know the List size upfront this way could improve performance slightly… but the gain is going to be so small you may as well use the version you prefer to maintain.

Comment: Have you noticed this thread is 6 years old?  (And my second answer directly handles his example of using `Array` instead of `int[]`.)

Answer (score 104):

Interestingly no one answers the question, OP isn't using a strongly typed `int[]` but an `Array`.

You have to cast the [`Array`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx) to what it actually is, an `int[]`, then you can use `ToList`:

```
List<int> intList = ((int[])ints).ToList();
```

Note that [`Enumerable.ToList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb342261(v=vs.100).aspx) calls the [list constructor](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,d2ac2c19c9cf1d44) that first checks if the argument can be casted to `ICollection<T>`(which an array implements), then it will use the more efficient [`ICollection<T>.CopyTo` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0efx51xw(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of enumerating the sequence.

Comment: Thank you, `Enum.GetValues` returns an Array and this helped me out making a list out of it.

Comment: I know this is old but you are right, the question is answer by this.  In my situation a dynamic deserializer returns a system array because it has to be prepared to accept any kind of data type so you can't preload the list until runtime.  Thank you

Answer (score 28):

The simplest method is:

```
int[] ints = new [] { 10, 20, 10, 34, 113 };

List<int> lst = ints.ToList();
```

or

```
List<int> lst = new List<int>();
lst.AddRange(ints);
```

Comment: One needs `using System.Linq;` for `ToList()` to work.

Comment: This doesn't work for `Array`. You need to cast it or call `.Cast<>` first.

Comment: have you tested this?

Answer (score 15):

In the case you want to return an array of enums as a list you can do the following.

```
using System.Linq;

public List<DayOfWeek> DaysOfWeek
{
  get
  {
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek))
               .OfType<DayOfWeek>()
               .ToList();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do like this basically:

```
int[] ints = new[] { 10, 20, 10, 34, 113 };
```

this is your array, and than you can call your new list like this:

```
 var newList = new List<int>(ints);
```

You can do this for complex object too.

Answer (score 5):

in vb.net just do this

```
mylist.addrange(intsArray)
```

or

```
Dim mylist As New List(Of Integer)(intsArray)
```

Comment: much better than using OfType<> (my VS2010 would not accept anything OfType...)

Answer (score 3):

You can just give it try to your code:

```
Array ints = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), 5);
ints.SetValue(10, 0);

ints.SetValue(20, 1);
ints.SetValue(10, 2);
ints.SetValue(34, 3);
ints.SetValue(113, 4);

int[] anyVariable=(int[])ints;
```

Then you can just use the anyVariable as your code.

Answer (score 3):

I know two methods:

```
List<int> myList1 = new List<int>(myArray);
```

Or,

```
List<int> myList2 = myArray.ToList();
```

I'm assuming you know about data types and will change the types as you please.

Comment: This appears to be just a repeat of the existing answers.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the existing method.. .ToList();

```
   List<int> listArray = array.ToList();
```

KISS(KEEP IT SIMPLE SIR)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is helpful.

```
enum TESTENUM
    {
        T1 = 0,
        T2 = 1,
        T3 = 2,
        T4 = 3
    }
```

get string value

```
string enumValueString = "T1";

        List<string> stringValueList =  typeof(TESTENUM).GetEnumValues().Cast<object>().Select(m => 
            Convert.ToString(m)
            ).ToList();

        if(!stringValueList.Exists(m => m == enumValueString))
        {
            throw new Exception("cannot find type");
        }

        TESTENUM testEnumValueConvertString;
        Enum.TryParse<TESTENUM>(enumValueString, out testEnumValueConvertString);
```

get integer value

```
        int enumValueInt = 1;

        List<int> enumValueIntList =  typeof(TESTENUM).GetEnumValues().Cast<object>().Select(m =>
            Convert.ToInt32(m)
            ).ToList();

        if(!enumValueIntList.Exists(m => m == enumValueInt))
        {
            throw new Exception("cannot find type");
        }

        TESTENUM testEnumValueConvertInt;
        Enum.TryParse<TESTENUM>(enumValueString, out testEnumValueConvertInt);
```