# Where is System.Linq in .NET 4.0?

Tags: .net, linq

I migrated an asp.net app to 4.0. Now I am getting an error "The type or namespace name 'IQueryable' could not be found". The reference to System.Linq is invalid and I can't find it in the reference list. Where did System.Linq go?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Make sure you are referencing `System.Core.dll` in your project.  The `IQueryable<T>` type is defined in that assembly (just as it was in .NET 3.5).

Comment: I had to add it manually in the csproj file because I was getting the error below when I was adding it in VS. Something has changed from 3.5 to 4.0 because the solution ran fine in 3.5

(A reference to 'System.Core' could not be added. This component is already automatically referenced by the build system.)

Comment: @Tony_Henrich, thanks, I had the same problem and adding it manually worked. Strange thing was: In vs2010 it build fine, but it didn't build on our CITE. But that fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have a reference to System.Core.dll in your project - I believe System.Linq resides there.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the System.Core.dll assembly.