# How do I convert an Array to a List<object> in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

How do I convert an `Array` to a `List<object>` in C#?

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with this question.. -5? Really?

Comment: +1 because it is a simple, effective question for which I did not find a duplicate on SO. (Downvoters should comment or reconsider.) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841/how-do-i-move-the-turtle-in-logo http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/podcast-58/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conversion of System.Array to List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603170/conversion-of-system-array-to-list)

Answer (score 120, accepted):

```
List<object> list = myArray.Cast<Object>().ToList();
```

If the type of the array elements is a reference type, you can leave out the `.Cast<object>()` since C#4 added interface co-variance i.e. an `IEnumerable<SomeClass>` can be treated as an `IEnumerable<object>`.

```
List<object> list = myArray.ToList<object>();
```

Comment: Be sure you're using System.Linq

Comment: Does this only work in VS2015? Under VS2012: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and no extension method 'Cast' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Thanks for `List<object> list = myArray.ToList<object>();`

Answer (score 50):

Use the constructor: `new List<object>(myArray)`

Comment: A nice thing about this style is that it creates and returns the list, so you can append more methods (e.g. `.Contains(userName)`).  Useful for cramming a bunch of logic into a one-line if statement :) .

Answer (score 15):

`List<object>.AddRange(object[])` should do the trick. It will avoid all sorts of useless memory allocation.
You could also use Linq, somewhat like this: `object[].Cast<object>().ToList()`

Comment: A nice thing about *this* approach is you are not constantly allocating new `List<T>` - you can `Clear()` and reuse an existing list.

Answer (score 10):

The List<> constructor can accept anything which implements IEnumerable, therefore...

```
        object[] testArray = new object[] { "blah", "blah2" };
        List<object> testList = new List<object>(testArray);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
private List<object> ConvertArrayToList(object[] array)
{
  List<object> list = new List<object>();

  foreach(object obj in array)
    list.add(obj);

  return list;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If array item and list item are same

```
List<object> list=myArray.ToList();
```

Comment: I had to add using using System.Linq; in order to have it working; not sure why.

Answer (score 3):

Everything everyone is saying is correct so,

```
int[] aArray = {1,2,3};
List<int> list = aArray.OfType<int> ().ToList();
```

would turn aArray into a list, list. However the biggest thing that is missing from a lot of comments is that you need to have these 2 using statements at the top of your class

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this,

```
using System.Linq;
string[] arrString = { "A", "B", "C"};
List<string> listofString = arrString.OfType<string>().ToList();
```

Hope, this code helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also initialize the list with an array directly:

```
List<int> mylist= new List<int>(new int[]{6, 1, -5, 4, -2, -3, 9});
```

Answer (score 0):

another way

```
List<YourClass> list = (arrayList.ToArray() as YourClass[]).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version:

```
  List<object> list = new List<object>(new object[]{ "test", 0, "hello", 1, "world" });

  foreach(var x in list)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("x: {0}", x);
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

This allow you to send an object:

```
private List<object> ConvertArrayToList(dynamic array)
```