# how to convert an array of objects to list

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conversion of System.Array to List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603170/conversion-of-system-array-to-list)

I want to convert the aPersonDataArr to a list `IList<aPersonDataArr> aPerList = ???` and viceVersa - from list to array. How can this be done, I am **not willing to use LINQ**. Is there any other way to do it?

```
class PersonData
{
    public string PersonName;
    public int Age;
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PersonData[] aPersonDataArr = new PersonData[2];

        for (int i = 0; i < aPersonDataArr.Length; i++)
        {
            aPersonDataArr[i].PersonName = "abcd";
            aPersonDataArr[i].Age = 10;
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: *Why* are you not willing to use LINQ? And why are you creating an array in the first place, rather than using a list throughout?

Comment: In answer to Jon Skeet, legacy code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just pass the array in List constructor.

```
IList<PersonData> aPerList = new List<PersonData>(aPersonDataArr);
```

To Convert back:

```
PersonData[] array = aPerList.ToArray();
```

If you don't want to use LINQ `ToArray` then Use [List.CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t69dktcd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
PersonData[] newArray = new PersonData[aPerList.Count];
aPerList.CopyTo(arrArray,0);
```

Comment: Technically `ToArray()` is part of LINQ.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, Yes its not, I just specified `list.CopyTo` in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Using Linq:

```
PersonData[] aPersonDataArr = new PersonData[2];
List<PersonData> list = aPersonDataArr.ToList();
```

Without using Linq:

```
List<PersonData> list = new List<PersonData>(aPersonDataArr );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //array into list
    List<PersonData> list1 = new List<PersonData>(aPersonDataArr);

    //list into array
    Array array1 = list1.ToArray();
```