# Convert jagged array of string to list of list of string in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to convert `string[][]` to `List<List<string>>`.

eg.

```
List<List<string>> listOfListReturned = new List<List<string>>();
string[][] twoDArrOfString = new string[2][];
```

I want to convert `twoDArrOfString`  to `listOfListReturned`

Please suggest, how to do it?

Regards,
Vivek

Comment: Can't you just use `toList()`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603170/conversion-of-system-array-to-list

Comment: @Dan Well that would give you a `List<string[]>`, so no he can't just use `ToList`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like the following will also work:

```
string[][] twoDArrOfString = new string[2][];

var res = twoDArrOfString
    .Where(inner => inner != null) // Cope with uninitialised inner arrays.
    .Select(inner => inner.ToList()) // Project each inner array to a List<string>
    .ToList(); // Materialise the IEnumerable<List<string>> to List<List<string>>
```

You need to handle nulls if the inner arrays have not been initialised.

If you aren't going to enumerate through all of these, you might want to drop the final `ToList` and simply work against the `IEnumerable<List<string>>` to avoid resolving all inner lists if you don't need to (taking advantage of the deferred execution of enumerables).

Answer (score 1):

Any reason in particular why you are doing this?

```
        List<List<string>> listOfListReturned = new List<List<string>>();
        string[][] twoDArrOfString = new string[2][];

        twoDArrOfString[0] = new[] {"a", "b"};
        twoDArrOfString[1] = new[] {"c", "d"};

        foreach (var s in twoDArrOfString)
        {
            listOfListReturned.Add(new List<string>(s));
        }
```

Or

```
        var result = twoDArrOfString.ToList();
        var listOfList = result.Select(x => x.ToList()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested just imagine it :)

```
        for (int i = 0; i < twoDArrOfString.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < twoDArrOfString[i].Length; j++)
            {
                listOfListReturned[i].Add(twoDArrOfString[j].ToString());
            }
            listOfListReturned.Add(listOfListReturned[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A more linq-ish version might be

```
List<List<string>> listOfListReturned = new List<List<string>>()
    {
        new List<string> {"A", "B"},
        new List<string> {"C", "D"},
    };

string[][] twoDArrOfString = new string[2][]
    {
        new [] {"A", "B"},
        new []{"C", "D"},
    };

var actual = twoDArrOfString.Select(arr => new List<string>(arr)).ToList();

for (var idx = 0; idx < listOfListReturned.Count; idx++) {
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(listOfListReturned[idx], actual[idx]);
}
```

EDIT: Adam's solution above allowing for empty rows is better.