# Best way to represent with List<> in C# what was an array of arrays in C++

Tags: c#

Back in the day I used to study C++... we used to do arrays of arrays at school, now called jagged arrays I see in C#.

However, I need to use a List<> whereby I can just add another array to it.

In C#, which is the best way to achieve a similar logic, such that each individual 'cell' of a List<> actually contains a whole array? All the examples I have found, simply render the content of an array linearly into a List, cell for cell, which is not what I want.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Use List of List i.e List<List<>>.

Comment: Create a class which has a `List<Whatever>`. Then use `List<YourClass>`. That way your code will make sense. Otherwise, nobody know what your List<List<double>> holds..

Comment: Please do look into the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603170/conversion-of-system-array-to-list

Comment: @Schuere thanks, that's what I was looking for - it's not difficult, just finding the right information. I'm still stuck in c++ headspace.

Comment: @Chaz, glad to be of help

Answer (score 1):

A List is generic, meaning it can be a list of any type. So, to have an array in each individual cell you could define a List like this:

```
public List<int[]> myArrayList;
```

Or you could even have a List of Lists:

```
public List<List<T>> myListOfLists;
```

Keep in mind that you will have to initialise both the outer List and the inner array/list in order to use them.