# c#, Soap, webservice. Convert Strings of Array, stringsofarray to List of strings, List<string>

Tags: c#, xml, soap, soap-client

I'm working on a webservice project where I'm using sql-server to extract data from a specific database to later send it to one or more clients such as Java applications and C# forms. Right now I'm connecting methods to a C# form and I'm having trouble to convert or in other words deserialize arrayofstring from xml to a List in c#.

I have done a converting method but its in my webservice, it looks like:

```
    public List<List<string>> Converter(SqlDataReader sdr)
    {
        if (sdr != null)
        {
            List<List<string>> list = new List<List<string>>();
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                List<string> tmp = new List<string>();

                for (int i = 0; i < sdr.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    string parameter = "";
                    try
                    {
                        if (sdr.GetFieldType(i) == typeof(string))
                        {
                            parameter = sdr.GetString(i);
                        }
                        if (sdr.GetFieldType(i) == typeof(int))
                        {

                            parameter = sdr.GetInt32(i).ToString();

                        }
                    }
                    catch (SqlException e)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    }

                    tmp.Add(parameter);

                }

                list.Add(tmp);
            }

            return list;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

This Method Converter will convert my arrayofstrings to `List<string>` but once I call the method in my proxy or controller it goes back to ArrayOfStrings.

My Proxy aka Controller:

```
   class Controller
{
    WebService1SoapClient client = new WebService1SoapClient();

    
    public List<List<string>> GetAllKeys()
      {
        List<List<string>> list = new List<List<string>>();
        List<string> tmp = new List<string>();
        var obj = client.GetAllKeys();///<--- when the method is called it should be List<string> type
     //but the WebService1SoapClient client = new WebService1SoapClient();  wont let the convert List<string> go through.

        foreach (var item in obj) // 
        {
            tmp.Add(item.ToString());
        }
        list.Add(tmp);
        return list;
      } 
    
    private void getListStrings()
    {
        
        List<string> list = client.GetAllKeys().ToList<string>();
        // cannot convert ArrayOfString to List<string> (what I want to do).

        
        List<string> list = new List<String>(arr);
        foreach (string item in client.GetAllKeys())
        {
            list.Add(item);
        }
        
    }
   
}
```

}

Note that the controller is in an other solution I'm running two visual studios or solutions 1.Webservice and 2. My c# win application where my controller is.

How can I convert ArrayOfstrings to `List<string>`?

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1603173/3279876

Comment: thanks for the ref but it didnt help me im still struggling @Sami