# Convert array of Strings to list of Integers?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, type-conversion

This is not a duplicate question because I'm specifically asking to convert an ARRAY of STRINGS to a LIST of INTEGERS. In other words, converting both different types of lists AND different object types at the same time.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

String[] allAnswers = {"2", "4", "1"}

int[] allAnswersInts = Arrays.stream(allAnswers).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();

List<Integer> allAnswerList = Arrays.stream(allAnswersInts).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is there a faster or more practical way to do this?

Comment: @napadhyaya This is not a duplicate question because I'm specifically asking to convert an ARRAY of STRINGS to a LIST of INTEGERS. In other words, converting both different types of lists AND different object types at the same time.

Comment: Though this question has already been answered and closed, there is a very simple (if not particularly performant) solution to that issue: linq provides useful extension methods like `ToArray` and `ToList`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603170/conversion-of-system-array-to-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to stream once.

Instead of using [`int Integer::parseInt(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-), you should use [`Integer Integer::valueOf(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-), so you don't have to call `boxed()` or rely on auto-boxing.

Then use `collect(Collectors.toList())` directly, instead of creating intermediate array first.

```
List<Integer> allAnswerList = Arrays.stream(allAnswers)    // stream of String
                                    .map(Integer::valueOf) // stream of Integer
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```