# Convert object array string to list string

Tags: c#

I have object value

```
{[
  "Temp",
  "Humidity"
]}
```

I want to Convert it to list string
I try

```
var res= (List<string>)value ;
var res1= value.OfType <List<string>>().ToList();
```

but it return null

Comment: is that a JSON above? doesn't look like a valid JSON to me

Comment: "I have object value" what does that exactly mean?

Comment: have you tried using: ```var res = new List<string>(value);```?

Comment: It might also debug representation of an object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conversion of System.Array to List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603170/conversion-of-system-array-to-list)

Comment: Did you try to cast it to an array? `var res= (string[])value `

Comment: @eldar i get this err Error: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type 'System.String[]'.

Comment: @Kristian i have error cannot convert from 'object' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>

Comment: Ok, now you know the exact type of it. So cast it to the correct type and then Deserialize that `JArray` into string array or list as you want.

Comment: I later saw that it is a JArray. Either make the conversion typed at source, or Deserialize it converting to string with ToString() (see below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Would be mess in a comment).
If that is coming in as a string, then you could use Newtonsoft from nuget to convert. ie:

```
var str = @"{[
  ""Temp"",
  ""Humidity""
]}  ";
var json = str.Trim(new char[] { ' ', '{', '}'});
var strlist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(json);
```

EDIT: Along the comments, you say it is a Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray, then this would do:

```
var lstString = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(myObject.ToString());
```